# How to sort query results based on specific field in mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am having my collection like below:

```
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(366),
    "file" : "xyz",
    "meta" : [{
                    "owner" : "user123",
                    "rating": "A"
    }]
}
```

I want to sort the query result based on owner

I have tried the below code but sorting is not working

Can anyone help me on this.

```
query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("meta.rating").is("A"));
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "meta.owner"));
mongoOperations.find(query, Test.class);
```

My Test Class:
Here i am having List which is another model

```
@Document(collection = "Test_Data")
public class Test{
@Id
private long id;
private String file;
private List<MetaList> meta;
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getFile() {
    return file;
}
public void setFile(String file) {
    this.file = file;
}
public List<MetaList> getMeta() {
    return meta;
}
public void setMeta(List<MetaList> meta) {
    this.meta= meta;
}
}
```

My MetaList class:

```
public class MetaList{
private String owner;
private String rating;
public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
}
public void setOwner(String owner) {
    this.owner= owner;
}
public String getRating() {
    return rating;
}
public void setRating(String rating) {
    this.rating= rating;
}
}
```

Comment: Is your `Test` class annotated with `@Document` and refer to the collection in database.

Comment: Yes, it is been annotated. Since meta itself is a list do i need to do something else

Comment: can you post your model class - `Test`

Comment: Not just the annotation, the whole class. You can edit your quesiton to post it.